# How to use spring restdocs to document request body that contains a JSON object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I'm using spring boot 2 to implement REST API service and would like to document it with restdocs.

The endpoint

```
POST /api/tags
```

with request body

```
{"name":"Some Tag", "description":"This is Some Tag"}
```

is used to add create a new Tag. I've looked through the restdocs documentation, but still can't find a way to document the request body's JSON fields, Can anyone help me to fill the missing part "......".

```
TagRequest request = new TagRequest();
request.setName("Some Tag");
request.setDescription("This is Some Tag");
client.post().uri("/api/tags").body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request)).exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk().expectBody(Integer.class)
        .consumeWith(document("add-tag", ...... )));
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to user `requestFields`

```java
client
                .post().uri("/api/tags")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(Integer.class)
                .consumeWith(
                        document("add-tag",
                                requestFields(
                                        fieldWithPath("name").description("...."),
                                        fieldWithPath("name").description("....")
                                )
                        )
                );
```

This is documented in official doc : https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-request-response-payloads

Comment: answer is correct, specifically in your case, it would be as following,

`requestFields(     fieldWithPath("name").description("some_text").type(String.class.getSimpleName()),
fieldWithPath("description").description("some_text").type(String.class.getSimpleName())
)`